# How to remove parentheses from JSON in start and end?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a Json Object look like ,

```
({
    "result":[{
        "key":"value".....
    }]
})
```

I don't know how to remove the parentheses from the starting and ending of the JSON like `(` and `)`. Please guide me.

Comment: What are all the Method's you tried ? Did you get any error's while trying that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to access JSONP data. You probably need to add ?callback=? to your URL

```
var url="http://www.somedata.com";
    $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(json){
        //loop through deals
        $.each(json.people,function(i,dat){
            $("#todaycal").append("<li>"+dat.name+"  "+dat.caseNo+"</li>");
        });
        $("#todaycal").listview('refresh');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Sake I took your JSON as a sample Input below

```
var test = ({
            "result":[{
                "key":"value"
            }]
        });
```

Using `JSON.stringify(test)` you removed these thing `(` start and `)` End

Output like below

```
{"result":[{"key":"value"}]}
```